# How to create lookup on a form control without using any Datasource field

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am creating an AX Form containing only one control, this control will give **lookup of workers**. I don't have any datasource in the form so cannot use any reference field on the control.

How to create this lookup on form control? Any help please!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new `ReferenceGroup` control to the form design and set the `ExtendedDataType` property of that control to `HcmWorkerRecId`. This will provide you with a basic lookup for the workers. Depending on your requirements you may have to [customize this basic lookup](http://devexpp.blogspot.de/2013/06/dynamics-ax-custom-reference-group.html).